# Proving a statement about determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries such that $A^2 = -I$, prove that $\det(A) = 1$.

This question is multi-part, but I happen to be stuck on this one. The previous parts showed: $A$ is nonsingular, $n$ is even, and $A$ has no real eigenvalues.

I know that $\det(A)^2 = 1$ since $A$ has real entries and $n$ is even, but am not sure how to show that $\det(A)$, which can be either $1$ or $-1$, is not $-1$. Does anyone know how to continue from here?

Comment: The Jordan normal form of $A$ must be diagonal with all entries $\pm i$ to satisfy $A^2=-I$, and the diagonal entries must come in complex conjugate pairs (because the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has real entries).  Hence there are equal numbers of entries $+i$ and $-i$, so that the determinant is $(-i\times i)^{n/2}=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ has no real eigenvalues yet is a real matrix, all its eigenvalues must come in complex conjugate pairs $a\pm bi$ with $b\ne0$. But $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2>0$, so the product of all eigenvalues of $A$ – its determinant – must be positive. Hence $\det A=1$.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to prove by induction that $A$ is similar to the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \dots & \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the answer is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix. If $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues, up to multiplicity. Then since $\lambda_j^2$ are also eigenvalues of $A^2$, $\lambda_j=\pm i$. then the characteristics equation can be written in the form
$$\chi_A(t)=\prod_{j=1}^n(t-\lambda_j).$$
Since $A$ is real matrix, the coefficients of $\chi_A$ are real. Hence the eigenvalues are in conjugate pairs i.e. the algebraic multiplicity of $i$ and $-i$ are equal.
$$\det(A)=\prod_{j=1}^n\lambda_j=i^{\frac{n}{2}}(-i)^{\frac{n}{2}}=1.$$

I hope this helps